# why does variable instantation contain syntax error?

Tags: python, syntax

I'm learning python. It gives syntax error in this script. I'm unable to figure out.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(
  host = str(Ip)
  user = "test"
  password="test1234")
```

the error:

```py
    user^= "test"
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

There is something wrong with the user variable instantiation according to the compiler.. I have no knowledge of how to solve this..

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `^=`?

Comment: Did you mean: `user = "test"`?

Comment: the code I'm using is user = "test".. I've pasted it wrong... the ^ comes from the compiler to indicate the supposed error --- I've edited the question

Comment: You are missing commas: `connect(host=str(Ip), user="test", password="test1234")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the =^ operator doesn’t exist, the code lacks indentation and commas between arguments you pass inside connect() call

Comment: `^=` does exist, it is used for an in-place xor, just like `+=` is in-place addition or concatenation. But as assignment is a statement, it is not valid syntax inside a parameter list.